# Different `align-items` value for each column using CSS grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve a CSS grid layout where, given a three-column layout with a dynamic number of items, each column uses a different `align-items` value. Put another way, each column of the grid would be aligned to a different starting point on the vertical axis, whether I can use `align-items` for that or not.

Not sure if it's possible, but in the example below I would like to somehow align the first column `center`, the second column `end`, and the third column `start`.

I'm using React for this and the data that populates the columns is fetched from an API, so the number of children in each column is always dynamic, otherwise I might be able to use `align-self` reliably. (But if someone can figure that out given the dynamic children constraint, great.)

```js
const items = [{
  name: 'Jane'
}, {
  name: 'Jill'
}, {
  name: 'Jon'
}]

const Grid = () => {
  return ( <
    div >
    <div>
    <p>The code here is what's used when fetching the data from an API. I don't see a *reliable* way of using align-self.</p>
    <
    div style = {
      {
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr',
        gridGap: 8
      }
    } > {
      items.map((item, index) => ( <
        div style = {
          {
            backgroundColor: "tomato",
            padding: 8,
            color: "#fff"
          }
        } >
        <
        span > {
          item.name
        } < /span> < /
        div >
      ))
    } <
    /div> 
    </div>
    <
    div style = {
      {
        marginTop: 32
      }
    } >
    <
    p > An example of what it should look like using align-self on some static data. < /p> <
    div style = {
      {
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr',
        gridGap: 8,
        border: '1px solid tomato',
        height: 200
      }
    } >
    <
    div style = {
      {
        alignSelf: "center",
        backgroundColor: "tomato",
        padding: 8,
        color: "#fff",
        height: 50
      }
    } >
    <
    span > {
      items[0].name
    } < /span> < /
    div > <
    div style = {
      {
        alignSelf: "flex-end",
        backgroundColor: "tomato",
        padding: 8,
        color: "#fff",
        height: 50
      }
    } >
    <
    span > {
      items[1].name
    } < /span> < /
    div > <
    div style = {
      {
        alignSelf: "flex-start",
        backgroundColor: "tomato",
        padding: 8,
        color: "#fff",
        height: 50

      }
    } >
    <
    span > {
      items[2].name
    } < /span> < /
    div >
    <
    /div> <
    /div> < /
    div >
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < Grid / > , document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what this is supposed to look like (an image would be useful) BUT it sounds as though `nth-child` might be useful here.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, sorry. Somehow the code snippet is missed up. Trying to fix it now so it will actually run.

Comment: @Paulie_D -- I couldn't get back in to edit my question but it looks like it's been edited to fix the broken code snippet. Now you can run the code and see the three column layout. Obviously the different alignment for each column isn't there, but you can get the gist.

Comment: Still not sure what this is supposed to look like.

Comment: @Paulie_D -- I added some more pseudo-code that uses align-self on the static data to show what it should look like. Given the data is dynamic, I don't see a *reliable* way to use align-self. Given the data is dynamic, I can't think of any reliable arithmetic I could use to apply align-self to the correct item.

Comment: What will it look like if those orange elements are different heights?

Comment: @AHaworth -- They're all going to be the same height.

Comment: You can achieve something like this using flexbox. Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-meadow-1estm?file=/index.html).